# Indirect Citation APA Style

Tags: citing, apa-style, multiple-citations

How do I code an indirect citation using the APA style, as here:
https://library.csp.edu/c.php?g=982644&p=8146056

(Smith, 2015, as cited in Jonson, 2019).

I want to refer to a figure made by an author with data retrieved from the World Bank.

Thank you

Comment: This isn’t answerable without telling us what bibliography package you are using.

Comment: I use these commands: \usepackage[nameinlink, capitalise, noabbrev]{cleveref} \usepackage{natbib} \bibliographystyle{apalike}

Answer (score 2):

The `natbib` package provides an alternate citation command `\citealp`  for `\citep`  which removes the parentheses but keeps the internal formatting of the citation callout. So to generate the citation you can use two of these commands inside parentheses that you provide manually.  There is actually a `natbib` macro to insert the parentheses: `\citetext`. The one possible advantage of using it over just typing the parentheses yourself is that it will adjust to the bracket style chosen (round vs square) automatically.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{Niyogi1997,
    author = {P Niyogi and Rc Berwick},
    journal = {Linguistics and Philosophy},
    pages = {697-719},
    title = {Evolutionary Consequences of Language Learning},
    volume = {20},
    year = {1997}}


@book{Chomsky1957,
    address = {The Hague},
    author = {Noam Chomsky},
    publisher = {Mouton},
    title = {Syntactic Structures},
    year = {1957}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{document}
This is a citation (\citealp{Chomsky1957} as cited in \citealp{Niyogi1997})
% alternative version:
% \citetext{\citealp{Chomsky1957} as cited in \citealp{Niyogi1997}}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I would use `\citetext` instead of a parenthesis. `\citetext{\citealp{Chomsky1957} as cited in \citealp{Niyogi1997}}.`

Comment: @Denis Thanks. I was unaware of that macro (mainly using `biblatex` these days). I've updated the answer to show both versions.